# ¿Cómo renombrar una impresora de Windows con Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi

Tengo esta rutina para cambiar el nombre de una impresora en Windows pero, al invocarla, no cambia el nombre, tampoco muestra ningún error<sup>1</sup>:

```
function TInformacionSistema.RenombrarImpresora(ANombreActual, ANombreNuevo : string) : boolean;
var
  LTamanio       : DWORD;
  LImpresoraInfo : PPrinterInfo2;
  LManejador     : THandle;
begin
  Result := false;
  try
    // Obtiene el manejador
    OpenPrinter(PWideChar(ANombreActual), LManejador, nil);
    // Obtiene el tamaño necesario para la estructura LImpresoraInfo structure en LTamanio
    GetPrinter(LManejador, 2, nil, 0, @LTamanio);
    // Asigna memoria
    LImpresoraInfo := AllocMem(LTamanio);
    // Llama GetPrinter de nuevo con el LTamanio
    GetPrinter(LManejador, 2, LImpresoraInfo, LTamanio, @LTamanio);
    // Se cambia el nombre
    LImpresoraInfo.pPrinterName := PWideChar(ANombreNuevo);
    // Se guarda la estructura con el cambio
    SetPrinter(LManejador, 2, LImpresoraInfo, 0);

    FreeMem(LImpresoraInfo);
  except
    exit;
  end;
  Result := true;
end;
```

La invoco de esta manera:

```
var
  iSys: TINformacionSystema;
begin
  iSys := TInforamcionSistema.Create;
  try
    iSys.RenombrarImpresora('Vieja', 'Nueva');
  finally
    iSys.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: Esta es una pregunta real que recibí, por otro canal, y quise compartirla junto a mi respuesta con la comunidad (espero que con el permiso del autor de la pregunta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encuentro varios problemas en tu código, te voy comentando:

### Trabajando con el API de Windows y sus errores

- [`OpenPrinter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/openprinter) es una función que devuelve un booleano indicando si fue exitosa o no y tu rutina no verifica esa salida.
- De manera similar [`GetPrinter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/getprinter) y [`SetPrinter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/setprinter) son funciones que devuelven un booleano indicando si tuvieron éxito o no.
- La mecánica del API de Windows, cuando una llamada falla, es llamar a la función [`GetLastError`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) y luego a [`FormatMessage`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage) para obtener información del último error que ha ocurrido.
- La RTL de Delphi nos provee la función [`RaiseLastOSError`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.RaiseLastOSError) que se encarga de realizar estos pasos con el API y eleva una excepción con la información del error.

### Manejo de excepciones y *leaks*.

- La rutina tiene un bloque `try`/`except` que se *come* cualquier error que ocurra dentro de ella, sin registro, sin explicación. Una mala práctica.
- Se reserva memoria con la función `AllocMem`, pero si ocurriera un error entre esta y la llamada a `FreeMem`, la memoria no se liberaría, provocando un *memory leak*
- Si `OpenPrinter` es exitosa, debe llamarse a [`ClosePrinter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/closeprinter), de otra forma el programa provocará un *handle leak*.

### Por qué no cambia el nombre de la impresora

Si si, todos los *problemas anteriores* pueden estar, pero ¿por qué no cambia el #$%& nombre?

- El problema principal es que, para obtener un *Handle* que pueda utilizarse para llamar a `SetPrinter`, hay que pasar el último parámetro a la función `OpenPrinter`, solicitando accesos elevados. (`PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS`)<sup>1</sup>
- Esto, a su vez, requerirá que tu proceso se encuentre elevado, de otra forma obtendrá un error `E_ACCESS_DENIED`.

### Ahora, la parte filosófica

- La función tiene una serie de comenarios que son realmente superfluos, en mi opinión, esto no añade valor, por lo que los quito.
- Finalmente, no veo por qué tener esto en una función, en realidad yo declararía un procedimiento. El *contrato* es que el procedimiento tiene éxito cambiando el nombre, o eleva una excepción, por lo que no hace falta evaluar ningún resultado al final.

El resultado de poner todas las correcciones a lo ya dicho, sería algo como esto:

```delphi
procedure RenombrarImpresora(ANombreActual, ANombreNuevo : string);
var
  lHandle: THandle;
  lpPrinterInfo: PPrinterInfo2;
  lPrinterDefault: TPrinterDefaults;
  lSize: DWORD;
begin
  lPrinterDefault.pDatatype := nil;
  lPrinterDefault.pDevMode := nil;
  lPrinterDefault.DesiredAccess := PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS;
  if OpenPrinter(PChar(ANombreActual), lHandle, @lPrinterDefault) then
  begin
    try
      lSize := 0;
      //esta primera llamada es solo para obtener el tamaño del buffer, ignoramos la salida
      GetPrinter(lHandle, 2, nil, lSize, @lSize);
      lpPrinterInfo := AllocMem(lSize);
      try
        if not GetPrinter(lHandle, 2, lpPrinterInfo, lSize, @lSize) then
          RaiseLastOSError;
        lpPrinterInfo.pPrinterName := PChar(ANombreNuevo);
        if not SetPrinter(lHandle, 2, lpPrinterInfo, 0) then
          RaiseLastOSError;
      finally
        FreeMem(lpPrinterInfo);
      end;
    finally
      ClosePrinter(lHandle);
    end;
  end
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: Una anécdota, es que esta parte me llevó demasiado tiempo... en mi humilde opinión, la documentación no es clara, dice que hay que abrir la impresora con `PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER` si se va a llamar a `SetPrinter`, pero esto, en Windows 10, siempre me devolvió acceso denegado. Fue hasta que probé con `PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS` (que incluye al primero) que tuve éxito. Si alguien sabe la explicación, la agradezco.